# Calling setState with nested object does not update state correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component that maintains state for several child components. Via `componentDidMount()` I am calling this function in the parent component from the child components:

```
change = (fieldset, field, data) => {
  this.setState({
    [fieldset]: {
      ...this.state[fieldset],
      [field]: data,
    }
  })
}
```

Think form/fieldset/field for the usage pattern, but with fields calling the above function.

The problem I'm having is that I believe I'm confusing React by calling this function so many times in quick succession, because state is not updated for all but one or two items.

I've tried using `Object.assign()` to avoid mutating state, but for the most part state has not updated correctly even at the point where I begin to read current start.

Is this against React best practices? Is there a better way for child components to call `setState` in a parent component?

Comment: Why not using updater function with `setState()`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'updater function' ?

Comment: Just double-checking, is `change()` a function that is in the parent that is passed to the children as a prop which they then call upon changing something?

Comment: @Toby https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate where *`setState()` does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading `this.state` right after calling `setState()` a potential pitfall. Instead, use componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (`setState(updater, callback)`), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update has been applied. If you need to set the state based on the previous state, read about the updater argument below.*

Comment: @samanime that is correct.

Comment: Is data always a scalar value (string, number, etc) or is it sometimes an object?

Comment: @ArupRakshit ah, okay - I'm not sure what I would callback - I'm using this pattern elsewhere, but the child components call this directly.

Comment: @samanime data is an object - in the child components I use the callback pattern suggested by ArupRakshit to setState, then call this function from each child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the way you update the state depends on the state itself you need to use a function instead of an object.

```
change = (fieldset, field, data) => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    [fieldset]: {
      ...prevState[fieldset],
      [field]: data,
    }
  }))
}
```

Functions will be applied one after another. So you wont override any pending changes.

From [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

> `this.setState({quantity: this.state.quantity + 1})`
>
> `this.setState({quantity: this.state.quantity + 1})`
>
> Subsequent calls will override values from previous calls in the same
> cycle, so the quantity will only be incremented once. If the next
> state depends on the previous state, we recommend using the updater
> function form, instead.

Comment: Yes this is what I meant.

Comment: This works perfectly - apologies @ArupRakshit, I didn't realize this was what you meant.

Comment: the state argument refers to prevstate?

Comment: @Omar I don't like to call it "prev". Because actually it is not previous in a sense but current state including pending changes applied so far.

Comment: docs says prevstate, but i can sort of see where you are coming from

Comment: @Omar Renamed to match the docs :) Just to avoid confusing future readers.